# Identifying relative location of label

Tags: cross-referencing

How can I obtain information about the location of a label relative to other text?

- Whether the label is on a previous page or the current page (i.e. appears in some previous lines, but on the same page).
- If the label is on a previous page; how many pages prior? E.g. 1 page before, 5 pages before.

It would be helpful to obtain some value, such as 0 for current page, 1 for the previous page, 2 for two pages previous, as that could be placed into an if-then.

Comment: Would you be able to supply a use case for your conditioning in the form of an example, even if it does not compile? The reason being that two different answers have been given using two different approaches, possibly due to two different questions contained in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This, perhaps is also a partial answer, since it addresses your first bullet.

The [`varioref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/varioref) provides `\vref` and `\vpageref` that "decorates" a page reference, depending on its location relative to the reference. Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varioref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/varioref
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\section{First section} \lipsum[1] \label{sec:first} \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4-5] \label{sec:second} \lipsum[6-8]
\section{Third section} \lipsum[9-12] \label{sec:third} \lipsum[13]
\section{Fourth section} \label{sec:fourth} \lipsum[14]
\section{Last section} \label{sec:last} \lipsum[15-17] \label{doc:end}
See the reference \vpageref{sec:last} or \vpageref{sec:second}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial solution: use `\pageref` to get the page number of where the `\label` was defined.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{pagedelta}
\newcommand{\pagerefdelta}[1]{%
    \setcounter{pagedelta}{\the\value{page}}%
    \addtocounter{pagedelta}{-\pageref{#1}}%
    \the\value{pagedelta}%
}%

\newcommand{\ShowRef}[1]{Section #1 is on Page~\pageref{#1}\par}%
\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\section{One-One}\label{One-One}
\lipsum[1-4]\label{One-Two}

\chapter{Two}
\section{Two-One}\label{Two-One}
\section{Two-Two}\label{Two-Two}
\section{Two-Three}\label{Two-Three}

\chapter{Three}
\section{Three-One}\label{Three-One}
\lipsum[1-9]

\newpage
\ShowRef{One-One}
\ShowRef{One-Two}
\ShowRef{Two-One}
\ShowRef{Two-Two}
\ShowRef{Two-Three}
\ShowRef{Three-One}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @cmhughes: It gives a solution for the second bullet point.

Comment: It does however have problems when TeX decides to move the reference to a new page while typesetting (as the pagecounter will be incorrect).

Comment: I wonder whether [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `\zpageref` is required here...?